# opening a default index.html file inside a folder (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I'm a real noob when it comes to asp.net/html. I'm developing a very basic web site using VS 2008. At this point it's mostly just html pages - no real ASP.NET

I have a root index.html and then a set of folders like
css/
images/
features/

etc. and index.html files inside them, so one can access it as

http://www.blahblah.com/features
and the index.html opens (it happens on my 1&1 basic web hoster)

But I can't test this locally because when the VS default web server opens my page for test, if I give /features

it shows the directory listing. I want it to open the index.html inside it...can't figure out how to make these friendly URL's WITHOUT USING ASP.NET core features (it's important - I don't plan to use ASP.NET for now)

any suggestion is welcome - all I want is a way to test it before upload to web site

Answer (score 1):

Thats a behavior I've seen before with the Development web server and something similar with IIS ( in that case you usually get a 403- denied).

unlike the default configuration for many other web servers the 'default page' for IIS is **default.aspx**.  In IIS you can configure the default page

(Right click on your virtual directory select  `Properties` then on the `Documents` tab you have the option to add/edit default content pages for your site)

but I don't know if a way of doing it for the Visual Studio Development web server.

For your scenario if you take your index.html files and rename them to default.aspx ( you do not need to change their content) you should see your 'index' page instead of the directory listing.

Comment: Perfect answer - thank you! I realized and configured my IIS and got it working the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The default file for Cassini (The VS Server) is default.aspx, or the currently selected .aspx file when you click "Run".  As far as I know there isn't any way to easily customize the "Default Document" as running in Cassini.

If you are not looking to use ASP.NET and want a simple workaround.  Setup your site in IIS, and view items that way.